# Simple request findBy(date) doctrine not working

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm

I have a simple question I just want to select all my Reservations by date, I tried with other properties like ID or email it works well but not the date :

```
$reservations = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()
->getRepository('LouvrePagesBundle:Reservation')->findByDateReservation($date);
```

The date format is exactly the same between my variable $date and my table, I really need a help

[DataTable screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dK1F.jpg)

Comment: maybe doctrine expects a date object (just guessing)

Comment: Check the profiler, what query gets actually run? And @user3791775 is probably right, using `DateTime` should get the job done

Comment: Problem is solved i used :

$dateObject =date_create($date); 

Thanks for your help

Comment: please, use new DateTime($dateString); instead of old structuralal date_create($dateString) construct.

Comment: Sorry to say that but... Everything is wrong here, your question doesn't give enough information to give you accurate answer and the solution you used to solved your issue is IMO not the right way, like @MateuszSip said, you should use DateTime object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comments by others and yourself, Doctrine expects a datetime object to search for. Generally said, never use date or times without the DateTime object in your code, you will enjoy the comfort of this object after you learned how to handle it. Especially when you have to deal with timezone problems.

tl:dr the solution is:

```
$repository->findByDateReservation(new DateTime($date));
```

---

By the way, because of your database image: dont use uppercase in database column-names. Set in your config file:

```
doctrine:
    # ...

    orm:
        # ...
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
```

then column names in the entity like `dateReservation` will be automatically changed to `date_reservation`.